# I want to iterate this in a priority order

Tags: python, string, list

This is the code I am using to iterate through two files and their lines what I want is to choose lines with # if they are in continual lines and then return back to the position where we started checking the # lines in the 2nd variable something like this:

go to file 1 if there is a line with # add it to the list if not add from file2 but if there are multiple lines in the file 1 with # add all the lines with # until you see a line without # then go back to the 2nd iterable but the 2nd var should be on the line where I left it.

I wanna alternate the two iterators variable between two files and lines but i don't wan't the other iterator's position to change when one of the iterator changes position this also affects with the difference in lines in both files.

This is the function i used for it.

```
    def process_files(file1_path, file2_path):
        result = []
        with open(file1_path, 'r', encoding="utf8") as file1, open(file2_path, 'r', encoding="utf8") as file2:
            file1_lines = file1.readlines()
            file2_lines = file2.readlines()
    
        for line1, line2 in zip(file1_lines, file2_lines):
            if line1.startswith('#'):
                result.append(line1)
                continue
    
            if not line1.startswith('#'):
                result.append(line2)
    
        return result
```

The files are too big to post and here is the sample input and output:

```
ssample1 = "text1.txt"
ssample2 = "text2.txt"
ooutput = "out.txt"`
```

```
text1.txt(file1):
#
#
#
#
fkjbja
akjfbajf
fajbfa
#
```

```
text2.txt(file2):
accessible
accessible
accessible


accessible


accessible
```

The output i am getting with this is a list, I use another function to put it inside another file:

```
['#\n', '#\n', '#\n', '#\n', '\n', 'accessible\n', '\n', '#']
```

The output i want is :

```
['#\n', '#\n', '#\n', '#\n', 'accessible\n', 'accessible\n', 'accessible\n', 'accessible\n', '#\n', 'accessible\n']
```

Comment: You can improve your question by fixing the formatting and providing sample input and output

Comment: What did you mean to do with line2 = line2-1 ? Isn't line2 a string ?

Comment: Maybe you want to add a sample of the two files (few lines) and the desired output?

Comment: You have not indicated how the code presented does not work.  Provide example input, and actual and desired output.

Comment: But what is supposed to happen if for example in file1 it encounters a line without the '#' character and tries to go to file2 at that location but file2 doesn t have the same number of lines so it doesn t find it?

Comment: A line either starts with # or it does not, the second test for not # is unnecessary.  Use  if-else rather than continue.

Comment: Can you describe step by step how you get `['#\n', '#\n', '#\n', '#\n', 'accessible\n', 'accessible\n', 'accessible\n', 'accessible\n', '#\n', 'accessible\n']`? I feel it doesn't match the description: _"go to file 1 if there is a line with # add it to the list if not add from file2 but if there are multiple lines in the file 1 with # add all the lines with # until you see a line without # then go back to the 2nd iterable but the 2nd var should be on the line where I left it."_ . Also _"the 2nd var should be on the line where I left it"_ what does it mean?

Comment: What i meant to say was that you need to alternate between the two file lists in a way that all of file2's # and all of file1 lines in the order of the file1 # present in the result when it returns in the way i described it. "the 2nd var should be on the line where I left it" This is where i was trying to describe how the position of the 2nd loop changes when i try to put file1's lines in the list. I would like it to stay on the same line where i left it.

Answer (score 0):

You iterate through two files simultaneously. When your code reach "fkjbja" the line from text2.txt is '\n'.

I think that can help:

```
for line1 in file1_lines:
   if line1.startswith('#'):
      result.append(line1)
    
   else:
      result.append(next(iter(line2)))
```

Comment: This gives me this output which is not i desire:

`
['#\n', '#\n', '#\n', '#\n', '\n', 'a', '\n', '#']
`

Answer (score 0):

I think looking into iterators might help with your answers. It would allow you to progress/process through the two files independently, if i get your task right. Maybe something like this works for you

```py
def process_files(file1_path, file2_path):
    result = []
    with open(file1_path, 'r', encoding="utf8") as file1, open(file2_path, 'r', encoding="utf8") as file2:
        for file1_next_line in file1:
            while file1_next_line.startswith('#'):
                result.append(file1_next_line)
                file1_next_line = file1.readline()
            result.append(file2.readline())
    return result
```

EDIT: I changed a previous version using next() to using readline(). The idea is still the same to walk both files line by line. However, the End-Of-File is not as easy as with the next() function.

EDIT2: I give it a try myself and as far as your question goes, the output with the code and the sample given is

```
['#\n', '#\n', '#\n', '#\n', 'accessible\n', 'accessible\n', 'accessible\n', '#\n', '\n']
```

This is because it is unclear if the line progresses for file two. In your given code, you use zip to combine the read lines, and this will progress file 2 automatically. You description lacks this details, imho. Also, since you pulling lines from file 1 filling in all lines with a '#', what happens with the rest of file 2 after you reached the EOF for file 1?
In any case, your initial question is looking for a way to read two files independently. Using next() or readline() is a close answer to that question.

Comment: Well,

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A:\Python\script.py", line 131, in <module>
    print(process_files2(ssample1,ssample2))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "A:\Python\script.py", line 121, in process_files2
    file1_next_line = file1.next()
                      ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'next'

Comment: I made edits to my original post, please consider.